# SQL Sub Query when joining table

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I am back to a similar issue I have had previously. It should be a simple thing, but cannot get my head around it.  Here is an overview of the tables and what I am trying to achieve with this subquery. I am using SQL Server 2008.

**Users**
This contains a list of users

**Login Audit**
Contains a list of login attempts. It holds the userID and the loginDate (datetime field)

**What I am trying to achieve**
I want to be able to show rows of users and their last login date from the audit table.

Here is my query, that would make sense from a laymans perspective! ;-)

```
SELECT  u.userID, u.fName, u.sName, l.loginDate
   FROM    Users AS u LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      (SELECT    TOP (1) loginDate, userID
                        FROM   LoginAudit) AS l ON l.userID = u.userID
   WHERE   (u.cliID = 1)
```

This just pulls back the last `loginDate`for the last user that logged in. I wanted all of the users to come back regardless if they logged in or not.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks
nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.userid, a.fName, a.sName,
  max(b.loginDate)
from 
   users a 
   left outer join lastLogin b on a.userid = b.userid
group by a.userid, a.fName, a.sName
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to replace your subquery with

```
SELECT userID, max(loginDate) as lastLogin FROM LoginAudit GROUP BY userID
```

And then replace "l.loginDate" in your main query with "l.lastLogin"

The functionality you want is provided by the MAX() function in an aggregate query, not the TOP() function.

Comment: I've just tried to tick both, but couldn't so had to opt for the first response. Both are correct!  Many thanks